# Java bytecode generation

Tags: java, compiler-construction, bytecode

I am writing my own little programming language with compilation into java bytecode as my graduation work, and having troubles with last part - bytecode generation. I already googled for some libraries for it, and even wrote some code using ASM library, but i am very unhappy with this library, because that event/visitor (i don't know how correctly call it) based architecture breaks my brain. So what i need:

- I need only to generate Java bytecode. Because many comparisons which i looked talked about transforming, i don't need it.
- I need understand, how bytecode and JVM works.
- There is no big deal about performance. It should be just acceptable.

And so, what java bytecode generation library more suitable for my case?

P.S. Also, i want to say, that i don't fully reject ASM, maybe it is good, but in this case i need something to understand this architecture, because now i just cant imagine how properly work with it.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/index.html, especially [chapter 3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-3.html),  [chapter 4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html) and  [chapter 6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html)

Comment: Welcome to SO saroff. Please avoid asking for help with finding software, links, books etc as such questions are [considered off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need understand, how bytecode and JVM works.

Yes. This is likely a major reason why you're having trouble using ASM. Most likely, the library documentation assumes you are already familiar with this. Skimming the Java Virtual Machine Specification will give you a basic idea of how the bytecode stuff works.

Comment: I already learned some bytecode basics, and very low-level bytecode manipulation in ASM it is not that thing, that i scary about. But i never hear before about this event-based model, and i don't know how to correctly work with it except tutorial examples.

Comment: @saroff Well, the only thing I can suggest is: pick the tutorial example that looks closest to what you're trying to do, start modifying it, and post a more specific question to SO when you get stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you look at using a higher level library like [ByteBuddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy/blob/master/README.md) however, what I do is generate Java code have it compiled at runtime e.g. [Java Runtime Compiler](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Java-Runtime-Compiler)

Reading a debugging Java code is often easier than doing the same for byte code.